# Why all methods are deprecated in PoolingClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

In Apache httpclient 4.*, why all the methods are deprecated? 
If all are deprecated , how can we use this class effectively.

When I do a PoolingClientConnectionManager.getTotalStats()

I see the following output

[leased: 2; pending: 0; available: 0; max: 20], and I never see available being above 0 at any concurrency.

Please advise.

Comment: For the reason stated in the class [Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html

The class `PoolingClientConnectionManager` itself is deprecated, so all methods are deprecated. Don't use the class. Instead, use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.